# HDFS read big file in paralle

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to read a big file who's size is 500GB from my hadoop cluster with 5 nodes. Can I read the blocks in parallel, or I have to read blocks one by one?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MapReduce/Hive/Pig then the blocks will be automatically read in parallel based on the number of blocks.

Assume, if you are performing wordcount on your 500GB file and the block size is 128MB then there will be 4 blocks and hence 4 Mappers (preferably as close to the data as possible - data locality) will be launched by MapReduce to perform wordcount in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for you answer :-). If I use TestDFSIO to read 10 500GB files concurrently, and the cluster can launch 50 mappers at one time. Can TestDFSIO read blocks in the same file in parallel?

Comment: TestDFSIO runs a MapReduce job, so yes TestDFSIO read's blocks in the same file in parallel.

Comment: If TestDFSIO reads blocks in the same file in parallel, how to determine the concurrent count?